# Does Google amp update our cache whenever we visit our amp site?

Tags: wordpress, google-amp

I have created my own Wordpress plugin for Google update cache.

However I'm not sure is my plugin work or not... whenever I update it, it doesn't change for a while. Sometimes it take less than 5 minutes to change, and sometimes it takes more than 10 minutes.

I always refresh my CDN site after I update my post, so I'll know my plugin is working if a website doesn't automatically updated from Google cache CDN site when it is visited.

So my question is:

Will our site be auto-updated from Google cache CDN site whenever we visited our CDN site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### the site will not change even we visit the site.

there's no document about it, but I already talked with some developer who knows about this stuff.